# Docker nginx websocket proxy== client closed connection while waiting for request

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket

I desperately trying to setup nginx proxy to websocket. Websocket connects but then I'm getting

> 2018/02/10 19:30:34 [info] 7#7: *238 client closed connection while
>   waiting for request, client: 172.18.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8888

Here's the minimal example:

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
error_log /dev/stdout debug;

http  {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    include       mime.types;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream tornado {
      server ws:8888;
      #server ws:8889; I may add another upstream here
    }

    server {
         add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
         add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

        listen 8888;

        server_name pychat.org;
        charset     utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 75M;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://tornado/;
             #>>> otherwise error 400
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_send_timeout 330;
             proxy_read_timeout 330;
             #>>>>>>
             #proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             #proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        }

    }
}
```

**server.py**

```
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler, WebSocketClosedError
from tornado import web
class MainHandler(WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print("ws mess" +  message)
        self.write_message(u"You said: " + message)

    def on_close(self):
        print("WebSocket closed")

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r'.*', MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./dockerfilenginx
    ports:
     - 8888:8888
  ws:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfilews
```

**Dockerfilenginx**:

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk update &&\
apk add vim nginx ca-certificates wget && update-ca-certificates
COPY ./docker/nginx-test.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "pid /tmp/nginx.pid; daemon off;"]
```

**Dockerfilews**

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk update &&\
 apk add python3 &&\
pip3 install tornado
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY ./server.py /usr/src
CMD python3 server.py
```

Then just try to open a WebSocket to the server, e.g. from browser console (shift+ctrl+i).

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8888')
ws.send("wsdata")
```

If I remove nginx proxy and just expose websocket port on docker - everything will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this proxy config for nginx, i use it for django and daphne

**proxy_http_version 1.1;** solved the issue.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://ws:8888;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't differ from my config. I tried it and getting the same. This configuration works ok w/o docker. Inside of docker I get what I wrote.

Comment: have you tried the proxy without the SSL (just ws://)

Comment: Yep, it doesn't matter, w/o ssl it doesn't work as well.

Comment: can you post the log from nginx (and the ws) when you try to access the server with the javascript

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and believed it was related to Nginx, but this was a red-herring.

In my case, my code was periodically raising an exception when sending a message on channels. This only became apparent when I introduced Nginx, which closed the "dead" channel (AFAIK). However, this **appeared like a timeout to me**, so I checked proxy timeouts and all sorts of things.

Eventually, I added some more logging to my code and realised the error was in fact caused partly by the following (example):

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                        'notifications', {
                            "type": "notification",
                            "data": some_packet
                        }
                    )
```

My consumer was expecting a "text" attribute when this message was received, and it didn't handle it well.

The socket then closed, Nginx dropped it, and I believed it was some issue with Nginx/Daphne/Docker-networking for 2 days.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Is there a question ?